# Find data stored after certain string - Python

Tags: python

Im trying to find a way to get the data stored at the end of a certain string in a .txt file using python. E.g:

```
bob: 22
jeff: 35
```

how could I tell python to ask for bobs age. Not the entire string.

Thanks
Torin

Comment: Please post the code you wrote for this

Comment: Show me your code, I'll show you mine.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the content of your a.txt file is like

```
bob: 22
jeff: 35
```

then this code should do your work

```
file1 = open("a.txt","r") # open the file for reading
lines = file1.readlines() #get each line by readlines to a array of lines
for line in lines:
    data = line.split(":")[1] # split the line with : so the second part is
 # the data that you want to reach
```